# Movie with a truck carrying abducted women

Tags: identify-this-movie

I just recall the trailer. Some guy is driving during the night with his wife who is asleep. There is a truck before us. For a split second, the doors of the truck open and the man driving can see women in a cage inside the truck. He tells his wife something like "Oh! Did you see that?", but she's asleep. He dismisses it as an illusion due to the fatigue.

Later, when they stop to fuel the car, his wife disappears, and the man is tracking down the network of women's abductors.

Comment: I know the movie you mean, but sadly enough, cannot remember the name of it or any actors either. But I think it was British. ;-)

Comment: @ChristianRau I thought it was an American movie. I saw the trailer couple of years ago and it seemed interesting, but since I couldn't recall the name I never got the chance to watch it :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it could be [**Hush**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1093369/) *(2008)*:

> Tired and irritable, **Zakes Abbott drives home along the motorway, his girlfriend, Beth, asleep beside him**.
>
> Failing to spot his exit he speeds across the causeway, cutting up a white van and barely avoiding an accident. Apoplectic with rage, the truck driver gives chase, and as he violently overtakes **the tailgate flips up revealing a woman bound and bloodied in the back. But before there is time for a second look, the door is slammed shut and Zakes is left bewildered and wondering if what he saw was real.**
>
> **Later at a service station, Zakes' fears grow when Beth goes missing**, and as he begins a frantic search, ...

- [Watch the trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXuUMDUIP5g)

Comment: Ah, at least that's the one I had in mind.

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Awesome. @ChristianRau you were right, from the trailer I can see that it was a British movie.